# Using ONE of microsoft word11 word12,word14 object library inside VB6

Tags: vba, vb6, ms-word

I'm developing a vb6 application that uses Microsoft office word.
each single word11,word12,word14 object libraries can make my application work. But How do I detect which version of Office is installed and thus which version of the "Microsoft Word Object Library" is available, and subsequently load it?

Note:  I don't want to use .net because many of my clients do not want to install .netframework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally:

- Code to the lowest version of Word you plan to support or do version tests before invoking any methods/properties that might not be supported under all versions
- You don't load a Word Object Library; you invoke an instance of Word and automate it.  Windows figures out which version of Word to invoke if there are multiple versions; once you have a Word object, you can query its version for your version tests.

On my PPT FAQ site, there's some general information about this; the same code should work in VB6 with only minor alterations, if any.

Controlling Office Applications from PowerPoint (by Naresh Nichani and Brian Reilly)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00795_Controlling_Office_Applications_from_PowerPoint_-by_Naresh_Nichani_and_Brian_Reilly-.htm

Answer (score 2):

Either use late binding (`... As Object`) or build against the earliest version you want to support. The object libraries are backwards compataible and COM handles the versioning so you will always get the latest version installed.